# MySQL PXC Gcache calculation

Tags: mysql, galera, percona-xtradb-cluster

I was trying ti figure out how to calculate the right gcache for my server and came across the following post discussing just how to do that:

```
https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/09/08/calculate-correct-size-percona-xtradb-clusters-gcache/
```

In the post, the talk about doing the following to get the values needed for the calculation:

```
show global status like 'wsrep_received_bytes';
show global status like 'wsrep_replicated_bytes';
select sleep(60);
show global status like 'wsrep_received_bytes';
show global status like 'wsrep_replicated_bytes';
```

My question is, will running the select sleep(60) in production block all reads on MySQL (by keeping the mysqld thread busy)? How can i calculate the best gcache value in production?

Comment: Did you ask this somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

> will running the select sleep(60) in production block all reads on MySQL

Absolutely not. `SELECT SLEEP(60)` is for your connection. You don't have to run this; you can just watch the clock and wait 1 minute before running the other SQL again.

> How can i calculate the best gcache value in production?

Just follow the blog post; it is pretty simple. Get the values now, wait 1 minute, get the values again, multiply by 60 to get an estimate for 1 hour worth of changes. Set gcache to that size rounded up to the nearest 1GB.